# How to add custom subject line using hooks in contact form 7 (wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to set custom message on subject textbox after form load. So that I can set the custom values like customerID=1 and then wanted to place some if conditions by checking if cutomerID == 1 then add subject line "Hello john" and if customerID==2 then add subject line "hello james" on the form textbox
like here:
[image]

So in my wordpress site I wanted to add hook to customise subject line based on the condition but dont know which hook is appropriate to do this?

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_form_autocomplete', 'my_change_subject' );

function my_change_subject( $wf7 ) {
  if($_GET['customerid'] == 1) {
  <script>$("input[name='subject']").val('hello john');</script>
  }
} ?>
```

Something like above but what hook I should use to do this?
I am also adding hooks site reference here: [contact form7 hook reference site](http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.5.1/hooks/#index=u)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone comes to this issue before but I found simple solution;)

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_form_autocomplete', 'my_change_subject' );

function my_change_subject( $wf7 ) {
?>  
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //console.log('coming here...<?php echo $_GET['cid'];?>');
        document.getElementsByName('your-subject')[0].value = "Customer Enquiry: <?php echo $_GET['cid'];?>";   
    });
    </script>   
<?php   

 }
```

} ?>